# Textbox with placeholder redirects to search results page without entering any value in IE

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

prevent page redirection on click of a submit button if the textbox with placeholder is empty in IE

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search for products" />
<input type="submit" value="click" class="submit-button" />
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, include some code.

Comment: what version of IE? how are you enfocing a value? does it only submit in IE but work in chrome/firefox?

Comment: the issue exists only in IE. chrome and firefox are fine. If I remove the placeholder from the textbox then the page does not redirect in IE. but, placeholder should be there.

Comment: which version of IE (placeholders are only supported in EI10 and above)